# Why spark sql will throw another partition location not exist exception?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

Below is my python code to get hive data with Spark SQL

```
warehouse_location = 'file:///path/to/warehouse'
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
spark.sql('select * from tbl where dt='A')
```

But Spark throw an FileNotFound exception about `/path/to/warehoues/tbl/dt=B`. Indeed I created partition B and had some data, then I deleted directory B directly (didn't drop partition B). But I think I should get no error if I only query `where dt='A'` as in Hive. Doesn't it matter `dt='B'`?

I didn't see source code about Spark SQL, I guess Spark will scan whole `warehouse.dir` and infer schema, so it will check validity. Can I mute this?